# Merging some List<double[]> within a List<List<double[]>>

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am struggling trying to merge a list of lists in a particular way. What I want to do is described below.

My input lists are:

List A = `List<List<double[]>>`

List B = `List<int[]>`

And the desired output is:

List C = `List<List<double[]>>`

There are some of the `List<double[]>` within List A that I want to merge (e.g. using  the Union capability in linq) and store the resultant list in a `List<List<double[]>>` called "ListC".

The indices of the Lists to be merged within ListA are stored in the ListB. If the elements are not supposed to be merged (their index doesn't appear in ListB) then we add them directly to ListC.

***Example***:

***Inputs***:

```
ListA = new List<List<double[]>>() { a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5};
```

where ai = `List<double[]>`

```
ListB = new List<int[]>() { new int[]{0,1,2}, new int[]{3,5} };
```

indicates that the lists 0-1-2 have to be merged into one. Same with lists 3-5

**Output**: ListC = `List<List<double[]>>` contains all the merged `List<double[]>` as well as all the unique `List<double[]>` of List A. That is:

--> c0= union of a0, a1, a2 "three lists to be merged into 1"

--> c1= union of a3, a5 "two lists to be merged into 2"

--> c2= a4 "is a unique list"

Note: duplicates are not a problem.

What would be a good way to achieve this?

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


class _unionLists
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        #region input lists
        //--------------------LIST A---------------------------------------------------
        //List a0
        var point1 = new double[] { 3, 3, 0 };
        var point2 = new double[] { 9, 6, 0 };
        var point3 = new double[] { 12, 8, 0 };
        var point4 = new double[] { 18, 8, 0 };
        List<double[]> a0 = new List<double[]>() { point1, point2, point3, point4 };

        //List a1
        var point5 = new double[] { 3, 3, 0 };
        var point6 = new double[] { 9, 7, 0 };
        var point7 = new double[] { 15, 7, 0 };
        var point8 = new double[] { 21, 15, 0 };
        List<double[]> a1 = new List<double[]>() { point5, point6, point7, point8 };

        //List a2
        var point9 = new double[] { 20, 13, 0 };
        var point10 = new double[] { 22, 16, 0 };
        List<double[]> a2 = new List<double[]>() { point9, point10 };

        //List a3
        var point11 = new double[] { 15, 19, 0 };
        var point12 = new double[] { 27, 19, 0 };
        List<double[]> a3 = new List<double[]>() { point11, point12 };

        //List a4
        var point13 = new double[] { 18, 20, 0 };
        var point14 = new double[] { 21, 19, 0 };
        List<double[]> a4 = new List<double[]>() { point13, point14 };

        //List a5
        var point15 = new double[] { 27, 19.5, 0 };
        var point16 = new double[] { 30, 5, 0 };
        List<double[]> a5 = new List<double[]>() { point15, point16 };          

        var ListA = new List<List<double[]>>() { a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5};

        //--------------------LIST B---------------------------------------------------
        var ListB = new List<int[]>() { new int[]{0,1,2} , new int[]{3,5} };

        #endregion

        //There are some of the List<double[]> within List A that I want to merge (e.g. using  the Union capability in linq) and store the resultant list in a List<List<double[]>> called "ListC".
        //The indices of the Lists to be merged within ListA are stored in the ListB. If the elements are not suposed to be merged (their index doesn't appear in ListB) then we add them directly to ListC.
        //
        //Example: 
        //  Inputs: ListA = new List<List<double[]>>() { a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}; where ai=List<double[]>;
        //          ListB = new List<int[]>() { new int[]{0,1,2} , new int[]{3,5} }; indicates that the lists 0-1-2 have to be merged into one. Same with lists 3-5
        //  Output: ListC= List<List<double[]>> contains all the merged List<double[]> as well as all the unique List<double[]> of List A. That is:
        //          c0= union of a0, a1, a2 "three lists to be merged into 1"
        //          c1= union of a3, a5 "two lists to be merged into 2"
        //          c2= a4 "is a unique list"

        var ListC = new List<List<double[]>>();


    }
}
```

Comment: What have you actually tried? You look like you have all the setup code here but I can't see offhand where you are actually trying to do the merge? Where exactly is your problem? Can you not think of an algorithm to do this? Do you have an algorithm in mind that you can't implement? Something else?

Comment: It might be worth just creating a data structure that represents your data more accurately. I'm not sure if this is supposed to be a matrix or a multidimensional array or something, but if you wrote a class to represent it, that would make it much easier to think about what transformations need to be applied to the data.

Comment: @Asad agreed - human brains are not great at keeping track of nested data structures, it's better to assign them some meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var elementsACount = ListA.Count();
var groupedElementsIdxs = ListB.SelectMany(e => e);
var ungroupedElementsIdxs = Enumerable.Range(0, elementsACount).Except(groupedElementsIdxs);

var result = new List<List<double[]>>();
// Merge and add the grouped elements.
foreach (var el in ListB)
{
    result.Add(el.Select(e => ListA[e]).SelectMany(e => e).ToList());
}
// Merge and add the ungrouped elements.
result.Add(ungroupedElementsIdxs.Select(e => ListA[e]).SelectMany(e => e).ToList());
```

Comment: @Jodrell It both compiles and works as I tested it with the data given in the question. Also, your answer contained some syntax errors that prevented it from compiling, but I see that you fixed it.

Comment: @Jodrell You are testing it against wrong data structure. See question: `var ListA = new List<List<double[]>>() { a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5};` in your code you test it against `List<double[]>` instead of `List<List<double[]>>`.

Comment: @Jodrell Yes, you've mistranscribed it. The `listA` is of the wrong type. That in turn produces an enumerable of the wrong type from the `Select`, and then you get that type mismatch error when you try to pass the `ToList` to `Add`.

Comment: @Asad, you are both correct, here's a demo of your code working. http://ideone.com/gBfWRk

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = new List<List<double[]>>();

foreach (var array in listB)
{
    var ld = new List<double[]>();
    foreach (var index in array)
    {
        ld.Concat(listA[index]);
    }

    result.Add(ld);
}

var indices = listB.SelectMany(arr => arr);

result.AddRange(listA.Where((list, index) => !indices.Contains(index)));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write

```
var C = A.SelectMany(x => x).Union(B);
```